# how to store the JSON format to database through api using Alamofire in swift4

Tags: swift4

```
{
    "Employee_ID" : "160",
    "Date" : "10-06-2019",
    "Time" : [
    {
      "In" : "10:30",
      "In_Location": "506/507, 1st Main RoadMurugeshpalya, Bengaluru",
      "Out" : "18:30",
      "Out_Location": "506/507, 1st Main RoadMurugeshpalya, Bengaluru",
      "Description" : "Designing Login Page",
      "Total" : "240"
    }
   ]
}
```

my actual code is:

```
    Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append("160".data(using: .utf8)!,    withName: "Employee_ID")
            multipartFormData.append(dateString.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "Date")
            multipartFormData.append(InTime.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "In")
            multipartFormData.append(self.locationName.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "In_Location")
//            for (key, value) in timeParams {
//                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
//            }
        }, to: "http://touramical-test.infanion.com:5000/api/save-tempion/", method: .post, headers: nil) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.response { answer in
                    print(answer.response?.statusCode as Any)
                }
                upload.uploadProgress { progress in
                    //call progress callback here if you need it

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("multipart upload encodingError: \(encodingError)")
            }
        }
```

it uploads only employee Id and date but not time parameters

Comment: You want to upload or save api resonse?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to transform your data in a struct like this:

```
struct Employer: Codable {
    var employeeID, date: String
    var time: [Time]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case employeeID = "Employee_ID"
        case date = "Date"
        case time = "Time"
    }
}

struct Time: Codable {
    var timeIn, inLocation, out, outLocation: String
    var timeDescription, total: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeIn = "In"
        case inLocation = "In_Location"
        case out = "Out"
        case outLocation = "Out_Location"
        case timeDescription = "Description"
        case total = "Total"
    }
}
```

And later try to do something like this:

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
var jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(yourTimeStruct) as? [String: Any]
Alamofire.request(yourURL, method: .post, parameters: jsonData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
    }
```